# google app engine eclipse installation fails

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I have Eclipse Juno and Helios on my pcs.   I have tried installing Google AppEngine plugin for Eclipse on both of them and there is always a failure.  I have seen posts on the web saying that Google has confirmed there is a problem with the latest issue and v3.2 will be corrected.   Is there any way I can install a version that will run with either of my 
Eclipse installations and has anyone heard when v3.2 will be published?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to install gpe on juno, i have been using it for some time, and just did an update last night to 3.1.2

]$ uname -a
Linux Device-7DB829 3.6.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Nov 18 10:11:22 CET 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

]$ ./java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  1.5.1.20121004-1506 
Eclipse Platform    4.2.1.M20120914-1800
Java EE IDE Feature 1.5.1.20121004-1506 
Google App Engine Java SDK 1.7.3    1.7.3
Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2   3.1.2.v201211121240-rel-r42

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I should have said that I am running on Windows 7 so I guess it is a bug in the Windows version.